# SFTP logging doesn't work

Tags: logging, sftp

I have some problemas trying to log sftp actions. I've configured some files but it doesn't write in the log file.

I'm using Debian 7.

**User configuration:**

> sftpuser02:x:1003:1003:SFTPUSER02:/home/www:/usr/lib/sftp-server

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -f LOCAL5 -l VERBOSE
Match Group sftpusers
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
```

**/etc/rsyslog.conf**

> local5.*                        /var/log/sftp.log

**ls -l /var/log/sftp.log**

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 ago  3 15:16 /var/log/sftp.log
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've restarted ssh and rsyslog services but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should work as it is (or on Fedora it does).

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work :( @Jakuje

Comment: the thing is, probably, that with internal sftp, openssh is using the old logging socket that was used by the server (the implementation between distribution varies a bit here). Did you try the same thing with normal sftp-server (copied with all dependent files into chroot) as a workaround?

Comment: Good point, do you know where I can find normal sftp-server? Is it in the server or I have to download it? Thanks @Jakuje

Comment: depending on the distribution. But fedora has it in `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`. To find out what are the dependencies, you can use `ldd`. I will probably create some answer where I will elaborate on this more.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **logger** to figure out the problem,like `ping 192.168.0.1 | logger -it logger_test -p local5.notice`,and `tail -f /var/log/sftp.log` see does it logging .

Comment: It works! :) Thanks. Now I have to figure out the problem. I don't know in which point I'm stuck, it's really strange. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this: http://practicingtechie.com/2012/09/16/sftp-file-transfer-session-activity-logging/ but It didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081637&p=12342713#post12342713

I needed a *dev* folder under chroot and create a rsyslog file.

Finally, it works :D !! I'm really happy hehehe.

Thanks a lot !